# UI not updating in IE, Array is displaying using ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular 5. I am displaying the result of multiple file uploads to an array and displaying the result on the UI with ngFor.

1. Loops through the selected files for upload. For each file it will call a function **uploadFiles()**
2. In that function service for saving the files are called and it will save the result by calling a function **addFileUploadResult()**.
3. In UI the values are not displaying.

I checked the component function and it showing the array have items in it. But the ui it is not reflecting.

Please refer the code below.

**file-upload-component.ts**

```
public startOperation() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.uploadFileList.length; i++) {
        this.uploadFiles(this.uploadFileList[i], this.uploadFileList[i].name);
    }
}

uploadFiles(file: File, fileName: FileName) {
    let fileUpload: FormData = new FormData();
    fileUpload.append("file", file);
    this.fileUploadService.uploadFile(fileUpload).subscribe(result => {
        this.addFileUploadResult(fileName + " : " + this.translate.instant(result.message).toString());
    }, error => {
        this.addFileUploadResult(fileName + "Error");
    });
}

addFileUploadResult(message: string) {
    this.uploadResult.push(message);
    if (this.uploadResult.length === this.uploadFileList.length) {
        this.showUploadError = true;
    }
}
```

**file-upload-component.html**

```
<div style="margin: 0px 90px">
    <ul *ngIf="show" style="font-weight: bold">
           <li *ngFor="let message of uploadResult" [ngClass]="message1.includes('Success') ? 'success' : 'failed'">{{message}}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you are doing a lot of push operations which is breaking change detection . why don't you push it to another variable and then assign the whole array to ``this.uploadResult`` ?

Comment: Did you enable the polyfills required for IE ?

Comment: @Ploppy Yes its enabled